# type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to do a radioselect horizontal align and I am receiving the following error message:type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'

What I am doing wrong?

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
   def render(self):
     return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))


class ApprovalForm(forms.Form):
     approval = forms.ChoiceField(choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES,
             initial=0,
             widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),
                             )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to inherit  `forms.RadioSelect.renderer` instead `forms.RadioSelect`. `forms.RadioSelect` is not instantiated so it doesn't have the attribute. So you are getting attribute error.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect):
   def render(self):
     return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))


class ApprovalForm(forms.Form):
     approval = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES,
            initial=0, 
           widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                 renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer
           ),
         )
```

Comment: renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'